# Accepting file and text inputs at the same time with Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have this form with two types of inputs, file and text. And I trying to save the image file (using Multer) in a local dir. and the text (using mongoose) in the database.

```
<form
     action="publish"
     method="POST"
     enctype="multipart/form-data"
    >
     <input type="text" name="textinput" placeholder="Title" />
     <input type="file" name="imginput" />
</form>
```

When i submit the form and try to handle both of the inputs (file & text), it prevents me from accessing the text because of 'enctype="multipart/form-data". I removed the enctype thing, and this time i couldn't access the image file.

```
async function addText(userInput) {
  const text = new Text({ text: userInput });
  
  const result = await text.save();
  console.log(result);
};

app.post("/publish", (req, res) => {

  // init upload
  const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: { fileSize: 1000000 },
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
      checkFileType(file, cb);
    },
  }).single("imginput");

  upload(req, res, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      if (req.file == undefined) {
        res.send("no file selected");
      } else {
        res.send("file uploaded");
      }
    }
  });
 
  addText(req.body.textinput);
};
```

Is there is a way that i can handle both of the inputs?

Comment: Put the enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute back. Try to console.debug the "req" and please share the output from the console.

Comment: The output is too long that StackO. wouldn't let me post it here

Comment: Try to identify if you see in that output the value you've entered in the form for "textinput" / or consider uploading an empty file for the example.

Comment: It is not there, I tried both ways and it didn't show up.

Comment: `req.body.textinput` won't be populated before the asyncronous `upload` function has finished. You shouldn't be explicitly calling `upload` yourself, nor creating `upload` *inside* your end point handler in the first place. Just [follow the examples in the documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/multer).